# Do fava beans need to cook longer than other kinds of beans?

Tags: beans

I typically cook my beans a total of 1:45h - 2h after soaking them overnight.  On a couple of occasions, I noticed that did not make fava beans as tender as others get after that much cooking.  Do fava beans need to cook longer than other kinds of beans to get them to be nice and tender or is there something done to them other than the length of cooking?

Comment: Is your bean source good? I've bought dry fava beans that no amount of cooking would tenderize. I believe they were packaged sometime during the Pleistocene epoch. I don't buy from that store anymore.

Comment: Goya 1 lb bags.

Answer (score 2):

First, they have to be released from their shell.  Then each bean needs to be peeled.  To make this easier, blanch the  individual beans for 30 seconds.  Once peeled, they can be cooked.  You don't need anywhere near an hour. Depending on the recipe 15 minutes or less.  It sounds like, maybe, you did not peel the individual beans.  Edit:  My advice is for fresh beans.  I realize now that you may have been asking about dried, which I am personally not a huge fan of.

Comment: whoa !!  peeling never occurred to me.  but i really have no intention of doing the tedious work

Comment: If you are using fresh beans, it is necessary...unless they are very small favas.

Comment: i was using dried